# getServletContext().getResourceAsStream() returns null

Tags: spring-boot, gwt, tomcat8

I'm using spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE.

I'm migrating an application from spring (a WAR) to spring-boot. It uses GWT which uses a servlet that depends on `getServletContext().getResourseAsStream()` method works as expected.
I've uploaded a reproducible project at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12868.

When doing a GET Request to http://localhost:8080/mymodule/afile.rpc you can see the file is returned, but if you execute http://localhost:8080/mymodule/dispatch a servlet is executed, the servlet uses `getServletContext().getResourseAsStream()` to return the same file, but null is returned in that case.

Any idea?

I saw similar issues filed before and marked solved, but maybe in spring boot 2.0.1 is failing again. Similar issues: #8525

Comment: can you paste the pom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [Andy Wilkinson](https://github.com/wilkinsona)

> Serving static resources from the classpath:static is a Spring MVC
>   feature that is auto-configured by Spring Boot. The servlet container
>   and servlet context know nothing about it is to be expected that the
>   attempt to access the file via the servlet context does not work.
>
> If you want static content to be served by the servlet container, you
>   should place it in a location where the servlet container can find it.
>   For example, in the root of an application packaged as a war file

I've finally adjusted the servlet to use the classloader instead the servlet context to pick the file.